# How many neighbors does a vertex has which are closest to a source vertex in random regular graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, randomness, random-graphs

Let $G=(V,E)$ be an undirected, random $r$-regular graph.

Let $s,t\in V$, and denote by $N(v)=\{u\in V\mid (u,v)\in E\}$ the neighborhood of $v$.

I'm looking for the distribution of the number of neighbors of $t$ which are closest to $s$, that is, let
$$C = \text{argmin}_{u\in N(t)}d(s,u)$$

($d:V\times V\to \mathbb N$ is the unweighted distance function which counts the number of hops between the vertices, i.e., the length of the shortest path).

- **What is the distribution of $|C|$? (fixing $r$ and $n=|V|$)**

---

I'm also interested in a few simpler questions:

- What is $\mathbb E (|C|)$?
- What is $\Pr(|C| > 1)$?
- Can we find any of these quantities for $r=4$, which is especially interesting for me?

---

The motivation for the question comes from peer-to-peer routing networks (of a specific type, which can approximately be represented as regular graphs).
Assume that the source node $s$ broadcasts a message to all vertices such that every vertex propagates the message upon arrival. I'm interested in the number of nodes we need to query before we find a neighbor that received the message already.

Comment: It sounds as if you're assuming that the result is independent of $|V|$ - is that the case?

Comment: @KlausDraeger - I don't think the result is independent of $|V|$ (e.g., if $|V|=5$, then the only $4$-regular graph is $K_5$, in which all of the neighbors are $1$ hop away from $s$, but this is not the usual case for large $|V|$).

Comment: That's why I asked, yes. What about the possibility that $G$ is disconnected? Is $C$ the whole connected component of $s$ except $s$ itself?

Comment: @KlausDraeger - $G$ may be disconnected, in which case the distance is $\infty$. $C$ is the set of neighbors of $t$, which may or may not include $s$ (but it does not contain $t$). This means that $1\le|C|\le r$.